# Nmap doesn't see every reachable host

Tags: monitoring

In my company there are 3 switches:

```
x.x.x.8
x.x.x.9
x.x.x.10
```

I monitor them on Netsight, sometimes with nmap, and of course pinging.
They are visible on Netsight and reachable by ping. I can log onto them by nmap. Nmap is showing only the last of them(10). Config is exactly the same and they are in stack so physically they are connected like this:

```
8-->9-->10
```

And 8 is connected to the router. I'm pinging from the remote server connected to the router.

What could go wrong and why? `nmap -sP x.x.x.*` is showing only the last host?

Comment: If the nmap client is on the same subnet as your switch management IPs, do you see them on your arp cache? *arp -na* on linux.

Comment: Sorry for bad english, should be:
"(...)and I can log onto them.B ut nmap is showing only the last of them(10)(...)"
Nmap client is on other subnet(234) than switches (258).To be precise:
Address 10.238.135.8 and 10.238.238.10 are exactly same switches with same config, but only .10 is visible in nmap:)

Comment: Are they really on a stack or are they simply daisy-chained? Since you have 3 IPs they probably are not a stack. So what network do you run nmap from? Is it in the same segment as Netsight?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may have one file called *x.x.x.10* on your current directory. Then bash will interpret the command as: **nmap -sP x.x.x.10**

I would suggest you scan this way: **nmap -sP x.x.x.0/24**

Comment: No diffrence if I use
nmap -sP x.x.x.* or
nmap -sP x.x.x.0/24 
Results still the same:)

Comment: Now I nmappped only one address : 10.238.135.8 and i get:

> Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping
> probes, try -Pn Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.01
> seconds



I'm looking up for another solution, I see that nmap ping address but somehow something blocks respond. Thank u guys and have a nice day.

Comment: Then it may be related to the ping being blocked from the host that is doing nmap. Does your switch have a route to your nmap host?